# Order of cost reduction application?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, crafting

Ive read through the cost reduction handbook and a few other locations on reducing the cost of an item during item creation.

Using my currently available cost reductions

25% extraordinary Artisan
10% apprentice

I'm seeing that the initial thought of application is an oder to reduction.

Item price 10,000G

10,000*0.50=5,000 
(1/2 base price to craft)

Then I'm told the reductions apply to the craft price?

Extraordinary Artisan says

Benefit

When determining the gold
 piece cost in raw materials
 you need to craft any item,
 reduce the base price by 25%.

1. Does it mean the base price of the item itself? 
   Eg 10,000*0.75=7,500

Or does it mean off the craft cost. 
Eg 5,000*0.75= 3,750

2. Is the crafting really additive?

(5000−((5000/100)*25)=3750)
3750-((3750/100)*10)= 3,375

Or

is it accumulative with the original reduction. 
5,000-((5,000/100)*35)=3,250

If the former, in what order do you apply these reductions?

Does the cost change if you apply them differently?

If you do this accumulative reduction bit by bit does it come out the same no matter what order you apply the reductions in?

Comment: I'm think this question may be a duplicate of [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68465/8610). Is it, or is there something the other question still leaves unanswered?

Comment: Actually... my entire questions was answered by both the first and second answer on there. The first answers what math to use and the second answers where these apply.

Comment: So to verify, that means.       5000−((5000/100)*25)=3750)           3750-((3750/100)*10)= 3,375 Right?