# Can you craft magic items without specific abilities--and therefore, requirements/costs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

Ghostwalk's *glove of the master strategist* is described as follows:

> This black leather glove is decorated with purple silk thread. It acts as a *glove of storing* and allows the wearer to use a *true strike* effect once per day.
>
> Caster Level: 6th; *Prerequisites:* Craft Wondrous Item, *shrink item*, *true strike*; *Market Price:* 3,600 gp; *Weight:* —.

Let's say you don't need the *true strike* ability. The glove seems to require a command word to activate it. As a 1st level spell (CL 1st) with one use per day, magic item creation rules imply that this ability is worth 1 × 1 × 1800 / (5/1) = 360 gp.

As such, could you craft what's essentially a *glove of storing* at CL 6th with only the Craft Wondrous Item feat, preparation of the *shrink item* spell, and 1,620 gp + 130 XP (half of the base price of 3,240 gp, plus XP costs)?

If so, what would happen if you gave the glove a requirement that the user have at least 1 rank in the Sleight of Hand skill? Is the 10% discount based on the "normal" cost of 1,800 gp (180 gp discount, seems unlikely) or the "intended" cost of 1,620 gp (162 gp discount, seems likely), or does doing so not apply a discount in this way (seems possible)?

Comment: (The *glove* is not a [use-activated](http://dndsrd.net/magicItems.html#use-activated) magic item. A magic sword is use-activated, for example, because it's "activated" by using it—it's swung at a dude. The *true strike* ability of the *glove* is activated by [command word](http://dndsrd.net/magicItems.html#command-word). I don't want to see the answers to your good question bogged down in tangents. `:-)`)

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99289/8610).

Comment: Honestly the activation method was something I was slightly unsure of anyway ;D Pretty minor price adjustment, but fixed for accuracy. I like looking through magic item creation rules, so the linked answer is indeed of interest, too!

Answer (score 1):

There are no “magic item creation rules.”

There are only “magic item creation guidelines.”

You can only make the items the DM says you can make, no more and no less. The guidelines explicitly tell the DM that the guidelines cannot cover everything and that the DM will be forced to make judgment calls. I highly doubt you’ll find many DMs willing to let you instantly craft magic items for free—or, equivalently, a DM may well want to know what magic is on it, what effect it is that’s putting it there, and then it *isn’t* something without specific abilities.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'd forgotten about that distinction. In what way would someone even be able to argue that a player would be able to "instantly craft magic items for free", though? I could picture taking this to the extreme, making a *glove of the master strategist* with neither the *shrink item* ability nor the *true strike one*--in other words, a mundane glove with a price of 0 gp. But I can't imagine any justification someone could use to try to go any further than that?

Comment: @47948201 Someone might make any argument at all; I don’t understand the question. I can’t imagine any argument being successful, so any given argument is equally poor in my mind.